# How to use a message that I made?

Tags: ros, messages, msg, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a new message following the tutorial i found on http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

But, how do i use it ?

I know how to use standard ros messages, like this:

```
// First i create the publisher
ros::Publisher fix_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>("fix", 1);

// Then I create the message.
sensor_msgs::NavSatFixPtr fix(new sensor_msgs::NavSatFix);

// Then, after I'm done editing, i publish the message
fix_pub.publish (fix);
```

But how do I do that, if I didn't make any class...
I tried to find the standard messages' classes, the sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h for instance, but i couldn't find it, can u guys help me?

---

So, if I want to use the message I must create another package for it?
Can't I create the message inside of my package? Because when I tried as you said using my package, it didn't work :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31779/how-to-use-a-message-that-i-made?/) by [BetoCC011](https://answers.ros.org/users/2041/betocc011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-13**:
You can create a message inside the same package. It is generally better to define all your messages in a separate package. That greatly simplifies inter-package dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I define my message type.

```
# MyCustomMsg.msg

Header header
float64 data
```

I then add my message's package to the manifest of my C++ node.

```
<depend package="my_custom_msg_package" />
```

Then, I import it into my C++ code.

```
#include <my_custom_msg_package/MyCustomMsg.h>
```

Set up a publisher:

```
my_msg_pub_ = n.advertise<my_custom_msg_package::MyCustomMsg>("topic", 1);
```

I then instantiate an instance of that message:

```
my_custom_msg_package::MyCustomMsg msg;
```

Finally, I fill it with data and publish it.

```
msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
msg.header.frame_id = "/world";
msg.data = 0.0;

my_msg_pub_.publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-13**:
In the message package's CMakeLists.txt you need rosbuild_genmsg().

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-04-13**:
Oh yes, I figured I'd miss something.

**Comment by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on 2012-09-18**:
In the message package's CMakeLists.txt you need rosbuild_genmsg().     I did that,but still it is showing that there is an error in my CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-18**:
Please edit your original question, adding the errors you are seeing. You should be fairly close to solving this problem.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-05-31**:
i have problem too... when i add "#include <msg/MyCustomMsg.h>" it send me "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Watch this YouTube Video, I had the exactly same question.

To the point and precise ::

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilRAlo5hi5o

---

Originally posted by [Sangeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29492/sangeet/) with karma: 31 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3